# Can't delete unlocked package from the dev hub

Tags: salesforcedx

I have created an unlocked package in my dev hub and I am not able to delete it. Per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_package_deletion.htm), you have to run the command `sfdx force:package:delete -p <package id or alias>` in order to delete it.

When I do it, everything seems fine, the CLI is asking me to confirm the action and shows success message, however, when I retrieve information about existing packages - "deleted" package still remains in the list. Screenshots below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the package ID in the deletion command?

Comment: Yes, doesn't help either.

Comment: The next option I would suggest is to turn on debugging for the sfdx CLI. If that shows nothing, try adding a debug log on the dev hub org against the developer user to see if you can spot anything there. If neither of those help, raise a support case.